# How to select a dropdown using selenium webdriver when the tag is not <select> but <a>

Tags: selenium, webdriver, dropdown

I am trying to select a dropdown using selenium webdriver but it is not successful.
When I run the program there is  an error showing

```
ERROR shown
No such element found, it should be SELECT BUT was a

HTML code 
UL class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active">
<li class="dropdown open">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="true">
Event 
<span class="caret"/>
</a>
<ul class="drop down-menu" role="menu">
<li>
<a href="create_event.jsp">Create Event</a>
</li>
<li class="divider"/>
<li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<li class="dropdown">
```

Comment: You have to click on the element to expand list, then click on the option. It's quite straight forward. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can use select the Create event by using this code : //ul[@class='drop down-menu']/li/a

In the same way you can do it for others as well. if you can give me entire code, then I should able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate element directly and click on it normally.

First click on dropdown and then click on required option.

Locate element of both and click on them one by one

Answer (score 0):

First click on the text box. If the text box loads the entire list then select the value using xpath. If it does not load the list then, type the content. Now the values will get loaded and click the content using xpath. If the content is not loaded then this will lead to element not found expedition or element not visible exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("id")));
```

for tagname u can use: By.tagname("");

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Example");

or
    dropdown.selectByIndex(1);

or
   dropdown.selectByValue("abc");
```

try with this